# How can I print a binary tree search on DESCENDING order?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

It's possible to print in-order with this

```
void printInOrder(noBinTree *n){
        if(n != NULL){
            printInOrder(n->left);
            printf(" %d ", n->number);
            printInOrder(n->right);
        }
}
```

and get

1, 2, 3, 4, 5

What do I need to do to print it in **descending** order (just by manipulating that function) and get 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 as result?

Answer (score 10):

```
void printInOrder(noBinTree *n){
    if(n != NULL){
        printInOrder(n->right);
        printf(" %d ", n->number);
        printInOrder(n->left);
    }
}
```

Just traverse Right -> root -> left

Comment: Property of binary search tree has the key for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going left-first means, going towards smallest value first in the current BST-subtree, so it gives sorted ascending order.

Similarly, if we move right-first then we would be going towards the largest value first. So, **Right -> root -> Left** gives sorted descending order.